Skype desktop Win 10 does not auto-download files - How to fix?
Skype desktop version 8.118.0: In Settings, I have the option to auto-download received files under Messaging  turned on. Still, in the conversation I see a PDF file  sent to me some days ago and Skype  does not allow me to open the file by clicking on its icon in the conversation or to Save it As... Also in the directory  for auto-downloaded  files, there is no file with this name. Apparently, Skype just ignored  the setting to auto-download received files. How to force Skype to respect this setting and  really auto-download all received files. In other words, I want to use Skype as email, that is to see everything that people send to me even after  some days , without manually saving everyhing in each  conversation every day. How can I  fix this and prevent Skype from losing the received  files with time?
